# How do I mount a Nuxt component with store and propsData for Jest Testing

Tags: jestjs, vuex, store, nuxtjs

I've been trying to find the answer to this for a couple of days now - hope someone out there can help!

I have a working project in NuxtJS, including Vuex store and modules.  Everything works great in the application, and I can use `this.$store.dispatch('cart/updateShippingAddress', addressObject)` in my code with no issues.

Now I'm writing my testing objects in Jest, using shallowMount.  In the past, I've passed propsData and data to the component being mounted, something like:

```
const testProps= { someData: 'goes here' }
const testData = function () {
   return {}
}
const options = { propsData: testProps, data: testData }
```

Then when I mount the wrapper, I use:
`await wrapper = shallowMount(Component, options)` - and this works great.

Now, when I have a Vuex store involved, I create the store using `const wrapper = shallowMount(Actions, { store, localVue })` works great also.

But how do I shallowMount a component with propsData AND a Vuex Store???  I've tried every permutation of parameters I can think of, and each time either the store or the propsData is not being passed correctly.  It's got to be something like `shallowMount(Component, { store, localVue, options })` but I just can't seem to crack this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried `shallowMount(Component, { store, localVue, ...options })`?

Because `store`, `localVue` and any other option must be at the same level:

```js
   shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      data,
      propsData,
      localVue,
      store,
    }
```

With the line you provided (`shallowMount(Component, { store, localVue, options })`) it gives:

```js
   shallowMount(MyComponent, {
      localVue,
      store,
      options: {
         data,
         propsData
      }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks!  I found a way around this by trial and error, but your explanation helps me understand it - appreciate the context!